# VSCode regex replace using regex group

Tags: regex, dart, visual-studio-code, regex-group

I want to replace `map["someKey"] as double` by `(map["someKey"] as num).toDouble()`, but I just can't get the regex working correctly. Can someone who knows more about regex tell me what to put in Find and Replace in VSCode?
I've tried `([a-zA-Z0-9]*) as double` and replaced this by `($1 as num).toDouble()`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Is `map["someKey"]` always some dictionary object?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had written `var` first and then wanted to be more precise with `map["someKey"]`, but I forgot to place it at the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
(\w+\["[^"]+"\]) as double
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/05zGKt/1). **Replace with** `($1 as num).toDouble()`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "\]                       '"]'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   as double               ' as double'
```